# Flutter: OpenFile.open("file_path") not working, giving Permission denied: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on android 13

Tags: android, flutter, dart, local-storage

Tried to open .pdf file like

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
                  await OpenFile.open('/storage/emulated/0/Download/myqr.pdf')
                      .then((value) {
                    log(value.message.toString());
                  });
                },
    child: const Text("Open File"),
)
```

But not working.

It gives error: *Permission denied: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*

Already added permisions in AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Requested permissons:

```
Future askRequiredPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.manageExternalStorage,
      Permission.accessMediaLocation
    ].request();
```

Comment: flutter doctor -v is fine with no errors.

Comment: Please tell which path this is about.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to the following package fixed this problem for me.

```
open_file: ^3.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

On an Android 13 device you will not ask for permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

You have it automatically for files created by your app.

Answer (score 1):

I Had this issue also and I moved to open_file_plus and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need these permissions for Android 13:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: Tried, but not working. Could you suggest any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach with permission handler https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler :

```
var permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;

        switch (permissionStatus) {
          case PermissionStatus.denied:
          case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
            await Permission.storage.request();
            break;
          default:
        }
```

In manifest only :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've provided the storage permission, it also asked for permission but still it shows denied status in logs.